# stompath - is it possible to migrate a user account from one directory to another

Tags: python, stormpath

I've created a bunch of users in one directory (`directory_A`). now, I'm going to switch to another directory(`directory_B`).

How can migrate all users from `directory_A` to `directory_B` without knowing their passwords.

I saw this script 
https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-migrate/blob/master/migrate/migrators/account.py

but It only works if I know the user password. 
any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I work at Stormpath. You can email support@stormpath.com to have them send over an encrypted export of all of the ***hashed*** user passwords for your tenant. If you do so, please send over your tenant name, tenant owner's email address, mobile phone number and mobile carrier (eg Verizon, T-Mobile, etc).

You can also 'copy' your users over without passwords by providing an empty passwords.json file to the migration script. Accounts will be created in the destination directory with random passwords, so you'll then need to issue password resets on those accounts so that your users can log in.

Edit: The migration script as written **copies** all Stormpath resources from one tenant into another, so you'll need to edit it if you only want a single Directory and the accounts inside of it copied over. If you don't want to do that, you can use the migration script as is and delete the resources that were copied over that you don't want.

Comment: if I have the hashed passwords, and I create (via script) the users in the new directory, would that work? because , I think stormpath servers would just double hash them .

Comment: If your hash is a supported type (https://support.stormpath.com/hc/en-us/articles/220973248-How-do-I-import-existing-users-and-user-data-into-Stormpath-) and you use the mcf flag when creating an account (https://docs.stormpath.com/rest/product-guide/latest/accnt_mgmt.html?__hstc=43953530.c91ad681278cb1bc6dddc7c944cab319.1466016184168.1466016184168.1466021867720.2&__hssc=43953530.4.1466021867720&__hsfp=4154956859#importing-accounts), Stormpath will not double hash.